# Printing gt table with rmarkdown::render when chunk code is in an external file

Tags: r, r-markdown, gt

I have monthly report generator that works fine with gt table inside a chunk, but not when the code for the chunk has a external source like the example below.

the main script

```
  rmarkdown::render('report.Rmd', output_file = paste0('report_', i, '.html'))
```

this way the report.Rmd works fine and prints the gt table

````
---
title: "Report"
author: "Me"
date: "`r format(Sys.time(), '%d de %B de %Y')`"
output:
  html_document
---

## Test

```{r first,  echo=FALSE, message=FALSE, results='asis'}
library(tidyverse)
library(gt)

```

```{r second,  results='asis', echo=FALSE, message=FALSE}
    #source("mtcars_gt.R")

mtcars %>% gt()
```
````

but this way not

````
---
title: "Report"
author: "Me"
date: "`r format(Sys.time(), '%d de %B de %Y')`"
output:
  html_document
---

## Test

```{r first,  echo=FALSE, message=FALSE, results='asis'}
library(tidyverse)
library(gt)

```

```{r second,  results='asis', echo=FALSE, message=FALSE}
    source("mtcars_gt.R")
```
````

mtcars_gt.R is just the gt

```
mtcars %>% gt()
```

Comment: Try with `readLines` ```{r code = readLines('mtcars_gt.R') }
````

Comment: great, it worked.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `readLines`

````
```{r code = readLines('mtcars_gt.R')}
```
````